# What's the difference between auid, uid, euid, suid, fsuid, obj_uid, gid, egid, sgid, fsgid, obj_gid in `auditctl`?

Tags: centos7, audit, auditd

My server is centos7.6 with auditd 2.8.5

In audit rule, I set:
`-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S adjtimex,settimeofday -F key=time-change`
But this rule also record normal `ntpd` activities,then I tried to revise this rule to:

```
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S adjtimex,settimeofday,stime -F subj_type!=ntpd_t  -F auid!=chrony -F auid!=ntp -F auid!=chrony -F auid!=ntp -F key=time-change
```

Should use `auid!=ntp` or `uid!=ntp`? I checked the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl):

> Each inter-field equation is anded with each other as well as
>   equations starting with -F to trigger an audit record. There are 2
>   operators supported - equal, and not equal. Valid fields are:
>   auid,
>   uid, euid, suid, fsuid, obj_uid, gid, egid, sgid, fsgid, obj_gid

I am confused, what's the difference between auid,  uid, euid, suid, fsuid, obj_uid, gid, egid, sgid, fsgid, obj_gid in `auditctl`?

Answer (score 2):

The audit manual assumes you are familiar with a POSIX security model and the many types of uids. Read [man credentials](https://linux.die.net/man/7/credentials) to get more familiar with that. However, that is incomplete, reference a security guide (such as the [RHEL Audit System Reference](https://access.redhat.com/articles/4409591)) for the rest. Notably:

> ### auid
>
> Records the Audit user ID. This ID is assigned to a user upon login and is inherited by every process even when the user's identity
> changes (for example, by switching user accounts with su - john).

---

A rule and its exceptions could be written on one line for efficiency. However, I sometimes start with more simpler rules. Easier to understand, and piece together examples.

---

auditd ships with example rules for auditing time change and ignoring chronyd.  Look at  `/usr/share/doc/audit*/rules/22-ignore-chrony.rules`:

```
## This rule suppresses the time-change event when chrony does time updates
-a never,exit -F arch=b64 -S adjtimex -F auid=unset -Fuid=chrony -F subj_type=chronyd_t
-a never,exit -F arch=b32 -S adjtimex -F auid=unset -Fuid=chrony -F subj_type=chronyd_t
```

"On a 64 bit platform, for the adjtimex call, when audit UID does not exist (not a login shell), and user name is chrony, and SELinux context is chronyd_t,  never log."

Actually, that example may have a bug. With chronyd running under systemd, and the example rules from `30-pci-dss-v31.rules`, I found audit events as uid 0.

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1552670692.891:1067): arch=c000003e syscall=159 success=yes exit=5 a0=7ffe0d94ae10 a1=0 a2=55e857a3af60 a3=0 items=0 ppid=1 pid=6487 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="chronyd" exe="/usr/sbin/chronyd" subj=system_u:system_r:chronyd_t:s0 key="10.4.2b-time-change"
```

ps reports it running as user chrony, and in the  chronyd_t context. So it is confined, but auditd reflects how systemd started it as root.

Try the condition `-F auid=unset -F subj_type=chronyd_t`. Not from a login shell and in the correct context is good enough for me.

(This subsystem has its quirks. The only place I was able to translate auid=4294967295 to unset is [the mailing list](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2015-January/msg00035.html).)